# How to select 1 column from a Range that includes multiple columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

Suppose the I have defined the range above as "Numbers"? If I'm trying to preform a calculation on only the first and second columns in this range and then I want to perform that same calculation on the first and third columns. Is there a way to select the values of one column from a range in VBA?

I have tried some things like .columns or .entirecolumn, but they don't seem to work. Maybe I'm not using them right?

Answer (score 0):

> <sup>... I'm trying to preform a calculation on only the first and second columns in this range and then I want to perform that same calculation on the first and third columns.</sup>

Let's pretend that 'preform a calculation' <sic> means 'multiply by 5' for the first two columns and 'multiply by 10' for the first and third columns.

```
dim i as long, j as long

sub main()
    with worksheets("sheet1").range("numbers")
        for i=1 to .rows.count
            for j=1 to 2
                .cells(i, j) = .cells(i, j) * 5
            next j
        next i
        for i=1 to .rows.count
            for j=1 to 3 step 2
                .cells(i, j) = .cells(i, j) * 10
            next j
        next i
    end with
end sub
```